# resultset object replace in RMI

Tags: java, mysql

i'm try to make POS system using java RMI technology. because i make custom resultset class to send data via RMI.it's work fine.but i copy to resultset to other resultset object.after doing some changers in one of object's change affect to other object.so why it's happening?.this is my code.

```
ResultSet rs = connect().getData("query");
ResultSet rs1 = rs;

System.out.println(rs.size());   // out ---> 1
System.out.println(rs1.size());  // out ---> 1

while (rs1.next()) {
   if (rs1.getString("Some_column_name").equals("0")) {
      rs1.removeRow(rs1.getRow());
   }
}

System.out.println(rs.size());    // out ---> 0
System.out.println(rs1.size());   // out ---> 0
```

Comment: There is no 'RMI technology' here. There is no such method as `ResultSet.removeRow()`. Unclear what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The variables rs and rs1 are referencing the same object.
In the loop the value zero is encountered and is thus removed from the resultset.
After that, you are printing the size of rs and rs1, which are now zero, since they are referencing the same resultset.